# Illustrator- Change Mesh Point Color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

So, I'm trying this tutorial and everything works fine, except point 5. http://www.vectordiary.com/illustrator/globe-tutorial/

I create a mesh with "Envelope Distort" selected with my mesh tool a nod and tried to color the Mesh point... but it doesnt work, I dont why or how but... dont know, I'm out of ideas. Edit contents is just to change the color of the rectangle, not the mesh points... so, how?

Comment: Hi Raoul. I rolled back your 'resolved' edit. We are a Q&A site, not a forum, and we prefer our posts stay formatted as questions and answers. The fact that you ticked Scott's answer as correct is sufficient to indicate that you have a fitting answer. Thanks for understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That tutorial is wrong**. Using `Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh` does **not** allow you to select mesh points and color them.

You **are not** doing anything wrong, the tutorial is inaccurate.

After drawing the box... choose `Object > Create Gradient Mesh` *That* will convert the box to a Mesh object which has anchors you can then assign colors to.